# How to join tables by overlapping jsonb values? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

To clarify the question, here's an example:

`Table venues`

```
id  match_ids (jsonb)
---------------------
1   []
2   [112]
3   ["25", 112]
4   [25, 112]
5   ["112"]
6   ["999"]
```

`Table sports`

```
id  object (jsonb)
--------------------
1   {"match_ids": [25, 112]}
2   {}
3
```

To join `venues` and `sports` so that the joined table has at least one element in common, how does the SQL statement have to look like?

Here's the expected outcome:

```
sports.id  venue.id  venue.match_ids
-------------------------------
1          2          [112]
1          3          ["25", 112]
1          4          [25, 112]
1          5          ["112"]
```

I wrote the following...

```
select * from venues
join sports on venues.match_ids <@ sports.object::jsonb->'match_ids';
```

... but this resulted in

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean -> unknown
LINE 4:  sports.object::jsonb->'match_ids';
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

(Here's a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5263069f490828288c30b6a51a181c8)

Any advice will be appreciated!

PS: I use PostgreSQL v13.

Comment: It seems a "native" array would be a better choice here instead of json. Or even a properly normalized model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by moving from `jsonb` to array and working with array intersect `&&`

```
select * from venues
join sports on ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(match_ids)::varchar)
&&
ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(sports.object::jsonb->'match_ids')::varchar);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5143f236235e4411c729f41a60c69012

**EDIT from the original poster**

Thank you so much @Ftisiot for this brilliant solution.
However, I found that this approach works if `match_ids` in `venues` has integers only. If the column has texts, it may not work. To select both texts and integers, `jsonb_array_elements_text` should be used.

e.g.

```
select * from venues
join sports on ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(match_ids))
 &&
 ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(sports.object::jsonb->'match_ids'));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=64f8fac38ccf73d38834c22e90ba4b2c

Answer (score 1):

Change the precedence with parentheses:

```
... on venues.match_ids <@ (sports.object::jsonb->'match_ids')
```